# mvn test doesn't follow tests order of dependsOnGroups

Tags: maven, selenium, testng

mvn test doesn't follow the order of execution of tests coded using TestNG dependsOnGroups annotation

I have tried running the project on Eclipse Run As TestNG Test. It executes in the expected order.

```
package com.chain;

StreamTest.java:

@Test(groups = { "main" })
public class StreamTest {
    static int durationBase = 2000;
    protected Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

    @BeforeClass()
    public void beforeClassMethod() throws InterruptedException {
        logger.info("Thread id: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        Thread.sleep((long) (durationBase * Math.random()));
    }

    public void testMethod1() throws InterruptedException {
        logger.info("Thread id: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        Thread.sleep((long) (durationBase * Math.random()));
    }

    public void testMethod2() throws InterruptedException {
        logger.info("Thread id: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        Thread.sleep((long) (durationBase * Math.random()));
    }

    @AfterClass()
    public void afterClassMethod() throws InterruptedException {
        logger.info("Thread id: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        Thread.sleep((long) (durationBase * Math.random()));
    }
}

EndStreamTest.java:

package com.chain;

@Test(dependsOnGroups = { "main.*" })
public class EndStreamTest {
    static int durationBase = 2000;
    protected Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClassMethod() throws InterruptedException {
        logger.info("Thread id: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        Thread.sleep((long) (durationBase * Math.random()));
    }

    @Test(dependsOnGroups = { "main" }, groups = { "cleanup" })
    public void testMethod1() throws InterruptedException {
        logger.info("Thread id: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        Thread.sleep((long) (durationBase * Math.random()));
    }
}   



testng.xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="classes" thread-count="10">
  <test name="Stonecress Tests">
    <packages>
      <package name="com.chain" />
    </packages>
  </test>
</suite>



POM.xml:

<build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.19.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Suite testng xml file to consider for test execution -->
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

Expected Results (works fine on Eclipse. Run Project as TestNG Test):

Jan 28, 2019 4:59:34 PM com.chain.StreamTest beforeClassMethod

INFO: Thread id: 1

Jan 28, 2019 4:59:36 PM com.chain.StreamTest testMethod1

INFO: Thread id: 1

Jan 28, 2019 4:59:38 PM com.chain.StreamTest testMethod2

INFO: Thread id: 1

Jan 28, 2019 4:59:39 PM com.chain.StreamTest afterClassMethod

INFO: Thread id: 1

Jan 28, 2019 4:59:40 PM com.chain.EndStreamTest beforeClassMethod

INFO: Thread id: 1

Jan 28, 2019 4:59:40 PM com.chain.EndStreamTest testMethod1

INFO: Thread id: 1

Jan 28, 2019 4:59:42 PM com.chain.EndStreamTest testMethod2

---

Actual Results (when run from command line with mvn test):

Jan 28, 2019 4:52:41 PM com.chain.StreamTest beforeClassMethod

INFO: Thread id: 15

Jan 28, 2019 4:52:41 PM com.chain.EndStreamTest beforeClassMethod

INFO: Thread id: 18

Jan 28, 2019 4:52:41 PM com.chain.StreamTest testMethod1

INFO: Thread id: 15

Jan 28, 2019 4:52:42 PM com.chain.EndStreamTest testMethod1

INFO: Thread id: 18

Jan 28, 2019 4:52:43 PM com.chain.EndStreamTest testMethod2

INFO: Thread id: 18

Jan 28, 2019 4:52:43 PM com.chain.StreamTest testMethod2

INFO: Thread id: 15

Jan 28, 2019 4:52:43 PM com.chain.StreamTest afterClassMethod

INFO: Thread id: 17

Comment: Can you post your <build></build> parameter values from the pom.xml because the given code is working fine for me, so there can be a difference in the build parameter from the pom.xml

Comment: Edited and added.